# How to position a setattribute value on the webpage and wrap text so button doesn't move

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using setAttribute value to create the remove button - how do I move the button away from the text entered and wrap the text so the button is in the same place?

Here is the js fiddle - The JS doesn't seem to work on it but it does work on my PC

https://jsfiddle.net/lewisjames101/aqxwuwbg/

```
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ToDoList</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>To do list</h1>
         <form id="todoform">
         <input id = "todoinput">
         <button type="button" onclick="todolist()">Add</button>
          </form>
          <ol id="todolist">
          </ol>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


JS
function todolist(){
    var item = document.getElementById("todoinput").value
    var text = document.createTextNode(item)
    var newitem = document.createElement("li")
    newitem.appendChild(text)
    document.getElementById("todolist").appendChild(newitem)
    document.getElementById ('todoinput').value = "";

    var removeTask = document.createElement('input');
    removeTask.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    removeTask.setAttribute("value", "Remove task");
    removeTask.setAttribute("id", "removeButton");
    removeTask.addEventListener('click',
     function(e) {
       confirm ("Are you sure?"); newitem.parentNode.removeChild(newitem);
    }, false);
    newitem .appendChild(removeTask);
}
```

[image: This is what I wanna achive]

[image: I would like line 6 to then wrap so the remove buttons are always aligned]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following style

```
#removeButton {
  margin-left: auto;
}
ol li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%; 
}
ol li div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```css
 
#removeButton {
  margin-left: auto;
}
ol li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%; 
}
ol li div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
    <script>
    function todolist(){
var item = document.getElementById("todoinput").value
var text = document.createTextNode(item)
var newitem = document.createElement("li")
var newitemDiv = document.createElement("div")

var newitemSpan = document.createElement("span")
newitemSpan.appendChild(text)
newitemDiv.appendChild(newitemSpan)
newitem.appendChild(newitemDiv)
document.getElementById("todolist").appendChild(newitem)
document.getElementById ('todoinput').value = "";
var removeTask = document.createElement('input');
removeTask.setAttribute('type', 'button');
removeTask.setAttribute("value", "Remove task");
removeTask.setAttribute("id", "removeButton");
removeTask.addEventListener('click',
 function(e) {
   confirm ("Are you sure?"); newitem.parentNode.removeChild(newitem);
}, false);
newitemDiv .appendChild(removeTask);
}

    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>To do list</h1>
     <form id="todoform">
     <input id = "todoinput">
     <button type="button" onclick="todolist()">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ol id="todolist">
      </ol>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I wrap the text so the button is always in the same place?

Comment: You want all buttons to be aligned?

Comment: all remove buttons, yes

Comment: Updated the answer. I had to change the js a bit for that

Comment: It doesn't wrap the text

Comment: iTS wrapping for me . Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ksi46xpf1j

Comment: line 6 in the second screenshot is there a way to wrap the text so remove buttons are inline?

Comment: But its wrapping for me :O . I dont know why it doesnt work on your machine. Did you include my css ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/bWVfHd See this link, it works for me. May be some other css on your page is affecting it

Comment: linked to a new js file and it worked thank you for your help your code worked - Sorry to be a pain :)